# Click/Tap on text in Table to view image

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
                        <tr>
                        <td>ID: VXD7524W</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>RESULTS: CLICK ME<hover img src="/Images/results/rd.1.26.22.jpg"/></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>STRAIN: SUPER LEMON HAZE</td>
                        </tr>
```

[image]
I'm trying to make the code for a table view an image on Click/tap when you click the text but I'm unfamiliar on how to do that in a table? and I cant find an answer here so I figured I would just ask.

Comment: Simply wanting to open up a lightbox when the text is clicked/tapped to view an image. Is that even possible in a table?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are exactly after but you can do something with a modal

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/spacemonki87/pen/qBpmmZV)

So yours will be something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<tr>
   <td>ID: VXD7524W</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>RESULTS: CLICK ME
      <img id="myImg" src="/Images/results/rd.1.26.22.jpg">
   </td>
   <td></td>
   <td>STRAIN: SUPER LEMON HAZE</td>
</tr>
```

Css:

```
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you just need to add javascript in your code that will help to change/call an image when you click. I just update some feature please check the code give below-

```
<script>
    // use changeImage as a function
    function changeImage () {
        //call image from source, while myImage is id of img tag
        var myImage=  document.getElementById('myImage').src="photo1.png";
    }
</script>

<tr>
    <td style="color: red;">ID: VXD7524W</td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="color: blue;">RESULTS: <!--Create button to change image with name changeImage-->><button onClick="changeImage()";>CLICK ME</button>
        <!--Keep src blank so that javascript fill out the source as mentioned above-->>
        <img id="myImage" src="" style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"/>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="color: green;">STRAIN: SUPER LEMON HAZE</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is extremely close. However I'm looking to try and get it like a lightbox style? where it opens big enough to see it and you can close out and the text stays normal/reverts to normal.